# Which URLS get you to the reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Which urls are possible, which allow you to view the reports from report in connection with *JasperReports Server* as a user. Like when I want to download the reports with wget in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to rest v2 api documentation with examples for calling reports
[REST v2: Running a Report](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v550/running-report)

You need server version that supports REST v2.